# How to group points within x meters with Postgis

Tags: postgresql, geospatial, postgis

I have long lat points with some duplicates that are very close but not exactly the same as one another. How can I group all points that lie within x meters of one another and return the centre long lat of each group?

Comment: What should happen, if f.ex. points `A` and `B` are not within x meters of one another, but there is a point `C`, which is within x meters of both `A` and `B`. Will `C` belong to both group of `A` and `B`? Or do you want `C` to be ignored?

Comment: Will k-means work for you? If so, see [this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11567/spatial-clustering-with-postgis)

Comment: A planned feature of the upcoming PostGIS 2.2 is `ST_ClusterWithin`, which groups geometries that are within a distance. See [the discussion](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/3023), if you are interested.